# R Arima order(1,0,0) forecast not giving what expected

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

My understanding of a simple ARIMA(1,0,0) equation is: $$y_t=\phi_1y_{t-1}+c+\varepsilon_t$$

Yet when I build an ARIMA(1,0,0) model on the `consumption` column of the `usconsumption` dataset in R, the forecast is not what I expect.

```
    > library(forecast)
    > library(fpp)
    > data(usconsumption)
    > tail(usconsumption[,1], 1)
    [1] 0.8753521
    > ar1 <- Arima(usconsumption[,1], order=c(1,0,0))
    > forecast(ar1, 1)
            Point Forecast       Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95   Hi 95
    2011 Q1      0.7979218 -0.03481309 1.630657 -0.4756363 2.07148
    > summary(ar1)
    Series: usconsumption[, 1] 
    ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

    Coefficients:
             ar1  intercept
          0.3553     0.7552
    s.e.  0.0726     0.0780

    sigma^2 estimated as 0.4222:  log likelihood=-161.06
    AIC=328.13   AICc=328.28   BIC=337.43
```

So using the `forecast` function gives 0.7979 as the forecast, but using the equation would give 0.8753521*0.3553+0.7552=1.066213. I'm not understanding the discrepency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple (equivalent) parametrizations for ARIMA models. There's the one you quote (sometimes called the *ARMAX* parametrization):

$y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + c + \epsilon_t$

And the equivalent *regression with ARMA errors* parametrization:

$(y_t - c') = \phi (y_{t-1} - c') + \epsilon_t$

The *forecast* package uses the second parametrization, so that the forecast is:

$\hat{y}_{t+1} = \hat{c}' + \hat{\phi} (y_t - \hat{c}') = 0.7552 + 0.3553 * (0.8753521 - 0.7552) = 0.7979$

The package author explains the difference between the two parametrizations and the rationale for choosing this one on [his blog](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). Mostly, when adding other regressors (other than the constant), this version is easier to interpret. Since the function forecast::Arima allows for other regressors, it makes sense to treat them all in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 y(t+1)=[phi]*y(t) + [1-phi]*C
        .3557*.87535 + .6443*.7552
       = .313 +          .485
       =.7979
```

The constant that is reported is the Left hand side constant in the model

$[Y(T)-C] = A(T)/[1- \phi * B]$

$[1- B]*Y(T)-[1-\phi * B]*C  = A(T)$

or

$Y(T)=\phi*Y(T-1)+ (1-\phi]*C +A(T)$